# I beat the wall of flesh but the jungle didn't grow restless

Tags: terraria

So I beat skeletron prime, The Twins, The Destroyer, and The Wall of Flesh (in that order) but in chat it doesn't say: The jungle grows restless... what do I do? Do I have to fight all the mechanical bosses again?

Comment: You did not defeat the mechanical bosses before beating The Wall of Flesh. That's literally not possible.

Comment: You have most likely beaten "The Eye of Cthulhu" and not "The Twins".

Comment: @Kaizerwolf It is very possible. Just bring the summoning items to a brand new world and use them at night time. The world does not have to have hardmode activated for you to be able to fight the mechanical bosses. See the wiki for details: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanical_Bosses#Notes

Comment: When this question's title appeared in my sidebar, at first I thought it was a heavy metal lyric.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure no Plantera Bulbs have appeared? It may have just skipped the chat message due to the unusual circumstances.

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode#Bosses - as mentioned, kill Wall - to get into hard mode. THEN kill Mechanical bosses. THEN Jungle Bulbs appear/grow which trigger Plantera. (THEN Golem. THEN Duke. THEN Moon Lord.)

Answer (score 20):

Killing the Wall of Flesh for the first time in any given world triggers hardmode, which is when the Corruption/Crimson and Hallow 'V' is generated. It is also the first step to the path to the Moon Lord boss. Though you can summon the mechanical bosses on any world (even pre-hardmode), the "jungle grows restless" message will not trigger unless you beat the mechanical bosses after the world is already in hardmode.

So in summary, you beat the bosses in reverse order - you should have killed the Wall of Flesh first, then the mechanical bosses. Now that you've got WoF beaten, you can beat the mechanical bosses again and the message will appear this time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to defeat the mechanical bosses while the world is in hard mode. So yes, fight them all again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if your world is in **Hardmode**. Easiest way to do so is to see if you have a natural Hallow biome in your world as the Hallow only exists in Hardmode. If it doesn't, kill the WoF. That should make the Hallow generate and in turn initiate Hardmode. After that, defeat all the Mech Bosses(they do not have to be killed in any order, however I suggest killing Destroyer first). A message should appear saying: "The jungle grows restless..." During this, Plantera's Bulbs will start to spawn. For more information, check the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera%27s_Bulb).

Answer (score -1):

Even though you may have defeated the mechanical bosses, you have to beat the WoF FIRST, because it only shows that message when you beat all the mechanical bosses in **HARDMODE**.

Comment: wonder why everyone below iElectro is being downvoted. oh well

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to kill all the mechanical bosses before the WoF. But, you may have killed the Eye of Cthulu, Eater of Worlds, and Skeletron instead of the mechanical bosses. But, if you did defeat the WoF before you defeated the mechanical bosses and then defeated the WoF again, then I do not know what is going on. It may be a glitch or you just have to defeat the bosses *again*.

Answer (score -3):

You have to kill the Wall of Flesh in order to enter Hardmode. The rest are Hardmode bosses. I assume that Wall of Flesh is actually first.

Comment: As it says in the comments on the question, it's possible to fight the mechanical bosses outside hardmode using summoning items. Even if it weren't, assuming the question is wrong doesn't provide an answer in this case.